# Reading Bluetooth RSSI value on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, rssi, windows-phone-8-sdk

I need to know the signal strength(RSSI Value) of a Bluetooth connection to a remote device on  a windows phone 8 device continuously( or I can even make it event based using a timer).

Till now I haven't found a API or function in SDK to achieve it, so any information on how to achieve it will be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the is no such a function available by the WP8 SDK. Try to use the wrapper made by [32feet](http://32feet.codeplex.com/). This will allow you to access the PAN(Personal Area Network) Components via .NET.